# How to filter an array of objects by unique ID and unique name?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that looks like the following:

```
    [
      {
        id: 1234
        name: Name1
      },
      {
        id: 5678
        name: Name1
      },
      {
        id: 1234
        name: Name1
      },
      {
        id: 5678
        name: Name2
      },
    ]
```

I want to filter out and remove the objects that have the same id AND the same name, so the expected result would look like the following:

```
    [
      {
        id: 1234
        name: Name1
      },
      {
        id: 5678
        name: Name1
      },
      {
        id: 5678
        name: Name2
      },
    ]
```

However I am only able to filter the array of objects by unique ID and I'm not sure how to cater for the extra condition of the same name:

```
data.filter((value, index, self) => {
  return (
    self.findIndex((v) => v.id=== value.id) === index
  );
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `&&` to include additional criteria that needs to be met: in your example, you want both the `id` *and* `name` to match:

```
const filteredData = data.filter((value, index, self) => 
  self.findIndex(v => v.id === value.id && v.name === value.name) === index
);
```

If you have multiple keys you want to consider and you don't want to write multiple `&&` statements, you can simply store the keys in an array, and then use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to enforce the match:

```
const keys = ['id', 'name'];
const filteredData = data.filter((value, index, self) => 
  self.findIndex(v => keys.every(k => v[k] === value[k])) === index
);
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Name1'
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    name: 'Name1'
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Name1'
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    name: 'Name2'
  },
];

const keys = ['id', 'name'];
const filteredData = data.filter((value, index, self) =>
  self.findIndex(v => keys.every(k => v[k] === value[k])) === index
);

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this straight forward solution by using [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [array.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

**Working Demo :**

```js
const obj = [
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Name1'
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    name: 'Name1'
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Name1'
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    name: 'Name2'
  }
];

const res = obj.filter((item, index, obj) => 
    obj.indexOf(item) && obj.lastIndexOf(item)
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend and add another condition in your `findIndex`. Something like this

```
data.filter((value, index, self) => {
  return (
    self.findIndex((v) => v.id === value.id && v.name === value.name) === index
  );
});
```

But this is time consuming. You're better of if you create a hash and use that to filter out.

```
data.reduce( (acc, current) => {
 acc[`${current.name}#${current.id}`] = current;
 return acc
}, {}).values()
```

What I'm doing here is to create an entry for each unique combination of `name`/`id` and then only get the values of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce` to iterate and return the final array by removing duplicates based on same `id` and `name` property; and to check duplicate object value you can use `Set` which will keep track of unique values.

```js
const objList = [
    {
        id: 1234,
        name: "Name1"
    },
    {
        id: 5678,
        name: "Name1"
    },
    {
        id: 1234,
        name: "Name1"
    },
    {
        id: 5678,
        name: "Name2"
    },
];

const removeDuplicate = (arr) => {
    const set = new Set();
    return arr.reduce((finalList, {id, name}) => {
        const key = `${id}${name}`;
        if (!set.has(key)) {
            finalList.push({
                id,
                name
            })
        }
        set.add(key);
        return finalList;
    }, []);
}

console.log(removeDuplicate(objList));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "locationone": "California, United States",
            "idtwo": 2,
            "locationtwo": "Atherton, United States"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "locationone": "London",
            "idtwo": 4,
            "locationtwo": "New Jersey"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "locationone": "London",
            "idtwo": 4,
            "locationtwo": "New Jersey"
        }
    ]

// for storing result
let ans =[];
// for storing all unique id
let unique_id =[];

for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    
    // checking from unique_id array if id alrady not present in that array
    if(!unique_id.includes(data[i].id)){
    //you can push whatever you want in your ans 
        ans.push({
            id: data[i].id,
            location: data[i].locationone
        });
        unique_id.push(data[i].id);
    }
}

// get all data with unique id
console.log(ans);
```